# Given a string, best way in Python to extract all integers in the string

Tags: python, regex, text

Given a string in unknown format, but expected to contain a known number of integers, I would like to extract those integers as a `List` or return an error if the number of integers does not match what is expected.

So for example, if the string reads `'This is a test 1 2 3 55'`, and the expected number of integers is `4`, it should return `[1, 2, 3, 55]`.

If the string reads `'(1 2 3 55)'`, and the expected number of integers is `6`, it should return an error.

In other languages I would split into words along all whitespace or punctuation, test each word for numeric status, and ditch the words that fail the test, but I am new to Python and am curious as to whether there might be a better approach.

Comment: Can you show your own Python approach and explain with reference to your code attempt, what difficulties you are having?

Comment: What research have you done to try and solve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression -

```
import re

s = 'This is a test 1 2 3 55'

expr = r'\d+'

print(list(map(int, re.findall(expr, s))))
```

If you don't want to use regex, this would also work -

```
s = 'This is a test 1 2 3 55'

arr = [int(x) for x in s.split() if x.isdigit()]

print(arr)
```

Output -

```
[1, 2, 3, 55]
```

As Michael Stern commented, if your input string has `floats` or a mixture of `int` and `str` (like '55ab9') and you want to ignore them, then the first approach would not work. You should split it by space and match each element to a regular expression `r'^\d+$'`.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that is recognizes 11.2 as [11, 2], while I would flag it as not an integer.

Comment: @MichaelStern I've addressed your concern.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a pretty simple, split by space is better than using regex.

Below is a program which can be up to your requirement. If you change the expected count from 4 to any other number, it will throw error as you specified.

```
 strdata='This is a test 1 2 3 55'
 num=[]
 expected_count=4
 for i in strdata.split():
    if i.isdigit():
            num.append(i)
 if len(num)==expected_count:
    print num
 else:
    raise ValueError('Numbers count not as expected')
```

Comment: the problem with the approach is that if the string takes the form '1, 2, 3, 4', as it may, the first three integers will not trigger the `is digit()` test because of their trailing commas.